# LinearLayout space distribution

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a complex layout situation in which an horizontal `LinearLayout` holds two other `LinearLayout`s. The content for those layouts is dynamic, can be any kind of views, and is generated at runtime from different independent sources.

I want to display both of them as long as there is enough space, and limit them to 50% of the available space each otherwise. So I want those child `LinearLayout`s to have `layout_width="wrap_content"` when there is enough space, and `layout_weight="0.5"` when there isn't. This means that the space distribution could be 10-90, 25-75, 60-40; it would only be 50-50 when there isn't enough space to show the entire content of both views. So far I haven't find a way to do this from XML, so I'm doing it from code. My question is can I achieve what I want using only XML attributes? Will a different kind of layout be able to do it?

Here is my current layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/options_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this cannot be achieved using only XML attributes.

Comment: By what could it be achieved then...? :) Do you know how this could be coded?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp" android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/options_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp" android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried it with textviews and this should work according to ure requirements.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! But how does it work? Is 'negative' extra space being allocated to the childs equally?

Comment: Weights is a tricky concept that I am trying to grasp too. In this case what happens is that both the layouts are given equal weights, and at the same time they are also made wrap_content. If there are no items in one and a number of items in another, wrap_content tries to wrap the empty layout and ends up with nothing, which results in the other one expand and fill its place. Had you made it fill_parent, the 2 layouts would take equal space even if one layout was empty. This is my understanding based on the experimentation. I plan to check out the implementation once i have the time :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not exactly work as required. When the sum of both childs width is larger than the available space and one is considerably larger than the other, the shorter one is not displayed entirely even when its size is less than half the available space.

Comment: You can try setting the parameter android:weightSum and use this to specify the maximum sum of weight each LinearLayout can have. Read this to understand how exactly the weight works http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Change layout_width="wrap_content" to layout_width="fill_parent" as you are using weight concept .

Comment: `layout_weight` indicates how much of the extra space in the `LinearLayout` will be allocated to the associated view. If I were to set `layout_width="fill_parent"` there wouldn't be any extra space to allocate.

Comment: yes according to me we have to set it fill parent and then assign weight atleast in your case. try it once might solve your issue?