# Divide space in LinearLayout depending on contents

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'd like to make myself a ListView with rows showing the name and the price of some product horizontally aligned.

I want to the price to get the width it needs and the name to wrap to a new line if width is running out.

So I used a horizontal LinearLayout, but name and price were overlapping. So I tried this  [LinearLayout space distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265021/linearlayout-space-distribution) solution but that way name and price are both wrapped.

Is there a way to have a 'take what you need' + 'take whats left' distriubtion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinearLayout is good when you know, how exactly you want to divide the space, either in a ratio or equally.

The described layout can better be achieved using `RelativeLayout`.

NOTE : You may want to use `minWidth` attribute to your name TextView, so that if price text becomes lengthy enough to cover whole width, name TextView is not pushed out of screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/price"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:text="Name extra text goes to next line"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Long Price Text Text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="28sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sample Outputs:

[image: Output1]
[image: Output2]

However, if you still want to use `LinearLayout` you can limit the size of name TextView using `maxWidth` property. But in this case if price text is small, your name text will still go to next line as you defined maximum width. But this won't happen in case of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Indeed, that achives what I need!